# Порядок вложенности циклов в генераторах списков

Tags: python, циклы, список, генераторы

Интересует следующее:

```
a = [[[[],...],...],...] # некоторый 3-мерный массив
l = [a[x][y][z] for x in range(5) for y in range(10) for z in range(15)]
```

Как будет инициализирован список `l`?

Так:

```
l = []
for x in range(5):
    for y in range(10):
        for z in range(15):
            l.append(a[x][y][z])
```

или так:

```
l = []
for z in range(15):
    for y in range(10):
        for x in range(5):
            l.append(a[x][y][z])
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = [['x1', 'x2', 'x3'], ['y1', 'y2', 'y3'], ['z1', 'z2', 'z3']]
l=[]
l = [[x,y,z] for x in a[0] for y in a[1] for z in a[2]]

from pprint import pprint as pp
pp(l)
[['x1', 'y1', 'z1'],
 ['x1', 'y1', 'z2'],
 ['x1', 'y1', 'z3'],
 ['x1', 'y2', 'z1'],
 ['x1', 'y2', 'z2'],
 ['x1', 'y2', 'z3'],
 ['x1', 'y3', 'z1'],
 ['x1', 'y3', 'z2'],
 ['x1', 'y3', 'z3'],
 ['x2', 'y1', 'z1'],
 ['x2', 'y1', 'z2'],
 ['x2', 'y1', 'z3'],
 ['x2', 'y2', 'z1'],
 ['x2', 'y2', 'z2'],
 ['x2', 'y2', 'z3'],
 ['x2', 'y3', 'z1'],
 ['x2', 'y3', 'z2'],
 ['x2', 'y3', 'z3'],
 ['x3', 'y1', 'z1'],
 ['x3', 'y1', 'z2'],
 ['x3', 'y1', 'z3'],
 ['x3', 'y2', 'z1'],
 ['x3', 'y2', 'z2'],
 ['x3', 'y2', 'z3'],
 ['x3', 'y3', 'z1'],
 ['x3', 'y3', 'z2'],
 ['x3', 'y3', 'z3']]
```